# JPA entity perform look up to find ID or insert new row into the table only if it doesn't exist when using Cascade.Persist

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I have two tables that look like:

Books (bookID , titleID, volumeNumber)

Titles (titleID, title)

My current entities look like:

```
@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "bookID"))
public class Book extends Identity{
    private Integer volumeNumber; 

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.Persist)
    @JoinColumn(name = "titleID")
    private IssueTitleEntity title;
}

@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "titleID"))
public class BookTitle extends Identity{
    String title;
}
```

The issue comes in regarding the title "lookup". Currently, jpa creates a new row in the Titles table and uses that ID for Books table. Is it possible for jpa to search the Titles table and see if it exists first and use that TitleID otherwise it will create it first? I suspect the issue lies with the Cascade type but have no idea which to use if that's the case.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: You are probably creating a new `BookTitle` instance which you set to the book instance. This always makes JPA/Hibernate assume that the title doesn't exists (as you create it new). If you want to reuse a title, it is on you to get a potential instance from the database and set it to the book

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without first querying the database for the id?

Comment: Not that I am aware of it. Also, would JPA itself also need to query the database first, to find the appropriate title object. Doesn't matter who does it, it has to happen

Comment: It's not clear from your question, but if you know that the title already exists in the db, you can use `session.getReference`. This way you create a reference to the title wihout querying the db.